# Translating an HTML5 dropbox into a file browse

Tags: javascript, html

I'm extremely unfamiliar with HTML5, and, well the jsp excel reader found here:
https://github.com/Niggler/js-xls

Well, the drop box requires HTML5 from what I understand, and the browser I am working with does not support HTML5. (My client does not either. If I could, I would tell them to just update their browsers to something more modern)

So my concern now is translating the file drop box into  a file browsing form such as:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" 
  action="action" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />
  <table width="600">
  <tr>
  <td>Names file:</td>
  <td><input type="file" name="file" /></td>
  <td><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
```

Here is the index.html that has the HTML5 box. Can someone assist in translating the box into a file browser? And have it do the same thing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
#drop{
border:2px dashed #bbb;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
border-radius:5px;
padding:25px;
text-align:center;
font:20pt bold,"Vollkorn";color:#bbb
}
#b64data{
width:100%;
}
</style>
<b>JS-XLS Live Demo</b><br />
<input type="radio" name="format" value="csv" checked> CSV<br>
<input type="radio" name="format" value="json"> JSON<br>
<input type="radio" name="format" value="form"> FORMULAE<br>

<div id="drop">Drop an XLS file here to see sheet data.</div>
<!--
<textarea id="b64data">... or paste a base64-encoding here</textarea>
<input type="button" id="dotext" value="Click here to process the base64 text" onclick="b64it();"/>
-->
<pre id="out"></pre>
<br />
<script src="xls.js"></script>
<script>
function get_radio_value( radioName ) {
var radios = document.getElementsByName( radioName );
for( var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++ ) {
if( radios[i].checked ) {
return radios[i].value;
}
}
}

function to_json(workbook) {
var result = {};
workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
var roa = XLS.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
if(roa.length > 0){
result[sheetName] = roa;
}
});
return result;
}

function to_csv(workbook) {
var result = [];
workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
var csv = XLS.utils.make_csv(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
if(csv.length > 0){
result.push("SHEET: " + sheetName);
result.push("");
result.push(csv);
}
});
return result.join("\n");
}

function to_formulae(workbook) {
var result = [];
workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
var formulae = XLS.utils.get_formulae(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
if(formulae.length > 0){
result.push("SHEET: " + sheetName);
result.push("");
result.push(formulae.join("\n"));
}
});
return result.join("\n");
}

var tarea = document.getElementById('b64data');
function b64it() {
var cfb = XLS.CFB.read(tarea.value, {type: 'base64'});
var wb = XLS.parse_xlscfb(cfb);
process_wb(wb);
}

function process_wb(wb) {
var output = "";
switch(get_radio_value("format")) {
case "json":
output = JSON.stringify(to_json(wb), 2, 2);
break;
case "form":
output = to_formulae(wb);
break;
default:
output = to_csv(wb);
}
if(out.innerText === undefined) out.textContent = output;
else out.innerText = output;
}

var drop = document.getElementById('drop');
function handleDrop(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
var i,f;
for (i = 0, f = files[i]; i != files.length; ++i) {
var reader = new FileReader();
var name = f.name;
reader.onload = function(e) {
var data = e.target.result;
var cfb = XLS.CFB.read(data, {type: 'binary'});
//var arr = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(data));
//var cfb = XLS.CFB.read(btoa(arr), {type: 'base64'});
var wb = XLS.parse_xlscfb(cfb);
process_wb(wb);
};
reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
//reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
}
}

function handleDragover(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
}

if(drop.addEventListener) {
drop.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragover, false);
drop.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragover, false);
drop.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with drag-n-drop. The problem is, if the browser doesn't support HTML5 enough good, it likely doesn't support File API (FileReader object in the given code and related stuff), so it *will be unable to read local files at all*, even if they are selected with the old-fashioned file browser. Honestly, I don't see the easy solution other than to move the operations with files to the server side.